# uisearchbar navigation bar color & status color

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am using uisearchbarcontroller. When search bar is active, status bar become grey color instead of original navigation bar color. May I know why it happen like that? Below is the code for how I set navigation bar color.

```
        [self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        {
            self.barTintColor = [Helpers getThemeColor:type];
            break;
        }
        [self setBackgroundColor:[Helpers getThemeColor:type]];
        self.opaque = YES;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set UISearchBar backgroundColor to color you want.

Example:--
    searchn.backgroundColor=uicolor;

Comment: yes. I set.         [self setBackgroundColor:[Helpers getThemeColor:type]];

But it is not okay

Answer (score 1):

`UISearchbarcontroller` presents search controller modally this causes change in status bar color. add code below to reset status bar color and then set background color for UISearchBar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Comment: Where shall I write? Is it in viewwillappear of that VC? Or?

Comment: add in viewWillAppear

Comment: it is still not okay. how shall i do?

Comment: check in info.plist `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `NO`

Comment: I have deleted my uiview and put back new uiview, uisearchbar, uitableview and it is now okay. Thanks for your help. Sam